# Make Jenkins use a subdomain without 8080 port behind apache2

Tags: jenkins

I’m failing at redirecting my Jenkins to use my subdomain (`build.core-network.us`) and not require :8080 port slapped behind it.

I’m on Debian Wheezy.

I use Apache (`proxy` and `proxy_http` are installed) and this is my `/etc/apache2/sites-available/build.core-network.us` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName  build.core-network.us:80
  ServerAlias www.build.core-network.us
  ServerAdmin piotr@riddle.pl

  ProxyPass         /  http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse  /  http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyRequests     Off

  <Proxy http://localhost:8080/*>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

</VirtualHost>
```

I made sure that `/etc/default/jenkins` has `--httpListenAddress=127.0.0.1 --httpPort=8080` as `JENKINS_ARGS`

And of course build.core-network.us has correct DNS entry (and it works fine when I add `:8080` port to it).

I found 4 other posts like this with 4 different VirtualHost recommendations and either they’re not for me or I’m failing to use them properly.

Update 1: I found errors in `error.log`:

```
[Fri Sep 26 17:33:59 2014] [notice] SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart
[Fri Sep 26 17:33:59 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Sep 26 17:33:59 2014] [error] proxy: ap_get_scoreboard_lb(0) failed in child 11990 for worker proxy:reverse
[Fri Sep 26 17:33:59 2014] [error] proxy: ap_get_scoreboard_lb(0) failed in child 11991 for worker proxy:reverse
```

Update 2: I did `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop` and then `start`, didn’t help.

Comment: So whats apache doing? 500, 404? Tell us the output! Look at apache access log and error log.

Comment: No errors in error log. Access log is OK too. When I visit my subdomain I’m simply getting normal "It works! This is the default web page for this server. (…)" page.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the error is here:

```
 ServerName  build.core-network.us:80
```

Drop the `:80`, that's not part of the `Host:` header. What's happening is that this isn't matching your request, and your system is falling through to another virtualhost (the first one loaded, if nothing explicitly matches).

`www.build.core-network.us` should be working now, which you can also use to test.

---

Also, you don't need  the `<Proxy>` section, that is only for forward proxy.

In most cases `ProxyRequests` is off already, so that's probably redundant, but doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot about the application path.
Default is /jenkins.

For example.

`Proxypass /jenkins http://localhost:8080/jenkins`

Comment: This is not my experience. I used to access my Jenkins at `build.core-network.us:8080/` and nothing behind it. Application wasn’t using `/jenkins` at the very end. Proof from my browser history: http://i.imgur.com/f4klEZz.png

Comment: Is jenkins working and you can access it?

Comment: Before I started meddling, yes, I could access it. The service is running. However, I found error in `error.log`, updated my post just now.